# reselecting items in listbox userform after manipulation and re-adding items

Tags: excel, userform, listboxitem, vba

First bit of code resorts the order, and then refreshes the list with the new order shown in the list box.

The listbox is currently set as "Single", but I want it to be established as a "fmMultiSelectMulti".  From a "Multi", I am able to gather the selected index numbers in a string with the public function call GetSelectedIndexes(userformNameHere).  (i.e. "0,4,7,8,9...")

My issues is once I cut and paste the certain rows around to resort the listbox, I want to be able to show the user that they still have the same values in the listbox selected.

```
Public Function GetSelectedIndexes(lBox As MSForms.ListBox) As String
'returns an array of selected index numbers in a listbox
Dim tmparray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim selCount As Integer
selCount = -1
'## Iterate over each item in the ListBox control:
For i = 0 To lBox.ListCount - 1
    '## Check to see if this item is selected:
    If lBox.Selected(i) = True Then
        '## If this item is selected, then add it to the array
        selCount = selCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve tmparray(selCount)
        tmparray(selCount) = lBox.ListIndex
    End If
Next

If selCount = -1 Then
    '## If no items were selected, return an empty string
    GetSelectedIndexes = "" ' or "No items selected", etc.
Else:
    '## Otherwise, return the array of items as a string,
    '   delimited by commas
    GetSelectedIndexes = Join(tmparray, ", ")
End If
End Function
```

here is the rest of my code which works with the single value selectable listbox:

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
' cuts + moves UP one cell...     ONLY WORKS IF FmMultiSelectSingle... 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mon").Activate

If Not MonMissions2.ListIndex < 1 Then
    selRow = MonMissions2.ListIndex + 2
    Range("B" & selRow).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown

'Reloads wing priorities list
MonMissions2.Clear
With MonMissions2
    List = Range("A2:A500").Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(List, 1)
            If Len(Trim(List(i, 1))) > 0 Then
                .AddItem Range("B" & i + 1).Value & "-" & Range("C" & i + 1).Value & "-" & Range("D" & i + 1).Value  ' populate the listbox
            End If
        Next i



    MonMissions2.ListIndex = selRow - 3
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Need to re-select previously selected ListIndex HERE
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End With

End If

End Sub
```

am I going to have to create 100+ variables for my dynamic listbox items to determine whether they were selected to begin with?   (listbox.selected(I) = true...)

Comment: Have you considered using several columns in your listbox, one shown, the others hidden? You could write the `Selected` status to a hidden column before sorting and retrieve the original setting from that column thereafter.

Comment: I guess my issue is with this case, the words in the listbox are a combination of strings from different columns separated by dashes.

I could still simply save an entire column with rows 1 - 100+ as a true or false (denoting which items were selected), and then reference that same column list as my true false for when I repopulate?

Comment: That's what I meant to suggest. In a multi-column ListBox, you have items like `ListBox1.Columns(1)`, `ListBox1.Column(2)` etc., all referring to the currently selected item, which is identified by `ListBox1.Listindex`. Presuming that column 1 is the bound column, the list box's `Value` is equal to `ListBox1.Column(1)`. Accordingly, if you wrote an item's `Selected` property to Column(2) before sorting, `ListBox1.Selected(n) = `ListBox1.Column(2, n)` would re-establish the previous selection after sorting.